# Silverlight Grid - Stretch to parents containersize but do not expand to acommodate children

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, grid, size

Is there any way to make a silverlight/wpf grid stretch to its parent width/height (using auto) but do no expand to acommodate children? In a Silverlight application I have the following:

Main Page, with a Frame:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Background="{StaticResource DefaultBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource DefaultBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
            <!--Some header content-->
        </Border>
        <sdk:Frame x:Name="Frame" Grid.Row="1" UriMapper="{StaticResource UriMapper}" ContentLoader="{StaticResource ContentLoader}" BorderThickness="0" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In this frame I load the desired page:

```
<navigation:Page 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" x:Class="MyNamespace.MyPage" mc:Ignorable="d"
       d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480"
        Title="{StaticResource PageTitle}">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <!-- Some header content -->
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Titletext" FontSize="13.333" FontWeight="Bold" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
            <RichTextBox BorderThickness="0" IsReadOnly="True" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" Padding="0">
                <Paragraph><Run Text="Text that will force the grid to expand."/></Paragraph>
            </RichTextBox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid></navigation:Page>
```

The frame in the main page is designed to deal with its content overflow ( through the scrollviewer), because a I have some pages that demand a minimum size.

The grid that holds the text box stretches to the parent, but when I put a large text inside the text box the grid resizes to the width of the text, making the horizontal scroll bar of the frame's scrollviewer appear. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require binding the max size of the grid to the max size of its parent ( this wouldn't work without hacks in Silverlight anyway, since binding to ActualWidth/Height is bugged). Any ideas?

Comment: When I use the following xaml it doesn't scroll ... what different behaviour are you looking for?   
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">Large text that fills the screen goes here</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

Comment: Your actualy Xaml attempt would be far more useful to us.  Also explain why you have a Grid in a Grid.

Comment: Code added! The grid inside a grid is because it will have some differences in the visual.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the wrapping like already posted AND change one property of the ScrollViewer:

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

to

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```